# Как правильно сделать отношение между такими таблицами в SQL?

Tags: sql

- Есть таблица пользователей (**User**).
- Есть таблица товаров (**Product**).
- Есть таблица групп пользователей (**UsersGroup**).

**Всего две группы: Пользователь и продавец.** Отношение между **User** и **UserGroup** - многие ко многим (один пользователь может входить во много групп, каждая группа может иметь много пользователей).

Пользователь, что относится к группе "**продавец**", может создать товар. Все могут покупать.

### Суть:

Как правильно сделать отношение между пользователем, чтобы иметь возможность получать созданные товары пользователем и купленные товары этим пользователем (актуально для роли продавца).

Я думаю, для продавца внешний ключ:

```
FOREIGN KEY (sellerId) REFERENCES User(id)
```

А для тех, кто покупает - JUNCTION таблицу **UserProducts**?

**Как решить этот вопрос правильно?**

Comment: `Product` - это описание товара или факт покупки? Если один пользователь купил два раза то же самое, нужно две записи про это хранить, грубя говоря, одна покупка сегодня, вторая - вчера? Если нужно хранить две записи, то для каждого факта продажи нужно хранить своего продавца?

Comment: Факт покупки. В нашем случае можно купить один раз. Но за подсказку спасибо.